# How to extract substring in SQL Server 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field with something like `okbogkbogkbokgbokgobkgobkofkgbokfgbo&name=fokdofkd&okfaos`

I'd like to extract the `name = value` from the data.

How can I do that using SQL Server 2008 in efficient way?
thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
;
With MyTable as
(
    SELECT 'okbogkbogkbokgbokgobkgobkofkgbokfgbo&name=fokdofkd&okfaos' FullString
    UNION 
    SELECT 'fkgbokfgbo&name=fokdofkd&okfaos' FullString
    UNION 
    SELECT 'okbogkbogkbokgbok' FullString
),
PatternIndex as
(
    Select 
        FullString + '&' FullString, 
        CharIndex ('&name=', FullString) + 1 LocationOfEqualSign, 
        CharIndex ('&', FullString, CharIndex ('&name=', FullString)+1) as NextBreak
    from MyTable
),
SplitNameValue AS
(
    Select 
        FullString, 
        CASE 
            WHEN NextBreak <> 0 THEN 
            SubString (FullString, LocationOfEqualSign, NextBreak-LocationOfEqualSign) 
            ELSE '' END
        as NameValuePair
    From PatternIndex
)
SELECT * 
FROM SplitNameValue
```

Returns

```
FullString                                                NameValuePair
--------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------
fkgbokfgbo&name=fokdofkd&okfaos                           name=fokdofkd
okbogkbogkbokgbok                                         
okbogkbogkbokgbokgobkgobkofkgbokfgbo&name=fokdofkd&okfaos name=fokdofkd

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I need to SELECT a field from the DB first.. I cant use hard coded value

Comment: @oshafran See my first select under the WITH - replace that with your SELECT statement such as `SELECT Youfield as FullString From YourTable`

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @oshafran that was happening to you because you did not have a `&name=` terminated by `&`. I modified the query to do the proper thing.

Comment: @Raj More: If the string ends with `name=...` (i.e. no terminating `&`), the substring is not extracted with your query. Although the OP may have no objection to such a case.

Comment: @Andriy M, I modified the SQL to append an ampersand to account for this

Comment: @Raj More: It works now all right, +1. Only one more thing that I had to fix when I tested it: after your last change the script became broken, because `FullString + '&'` was not aliased.

Answer (score 1):

This will work I think:

```
Declare @String varchar(100)

Set @String = 'okbogkbogkbokgbokgobkgobkofkgbokfgbo&name=fokdofkd&okfaos'

Select SubString(@String,CharIndex('name=',@String),len(@String))
```

This produces:

'name=fokdofkd&okfaos'

Comment: length 9999 is not right as there can follow more &name=value

Comment: @Matten - How do you know that? That's not indicated in the question.

Comment: in you given `@String` follow a `&okfaos` after `&name=fokdofkd`, I don't think `&okfao` belongs to the value revelator wants.

Comment: @Matten - you are right, it doesnt belong. only name=fokkofkof

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'name=' + SUBSTRING(field, CHARINDEX('name=', field), CHARINDEX('&', SUBSTRING(field, CHARINDEX('name=' ,field))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of...

```
select substring(ColumnName, charindex('name=',ColumnName,1),len(ColumnName))
```