# get all sub-strings within specified characters from a strings in SQL-2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get all sub-strings within particular characters, '#image' and '#' without using loop or what is the best way

```
declare @str nvarchar(max)='get all substrings #image:header# #image:footer#'
```

#### expected result

> Image
>
> ---
>
> header
>
> footer

Comment: Not sure, but think that it can be done using xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845387/1934137)
by using CTE recursively to strip out the string

```
declare @str nvarchar(100)='get all substrings #image:header# #image:footer# between specific characters'
declare @imageTokenStart nvarchar(8)='#image:'
declare @imageTokenEnd nvarchar(1)='#'

;WITH cte(msg,token)
as
(
    SELECT RIGHT(msg,(LEN(msg)- CHARINDEX(@imageTokenEnd, msg, CHARINDEX(@imageTokenStart, msg, 0) + 1)))
        ,SUBSTRING(msg, CHARINDEX(@imageTokenStart, msg, 0) + LEN(@imageTokenStart)
                , CHARINDEX(@imageTokenEnd, msg, CHARINDEX(@imageTokenStart, msg, 0) + 1) - (
                    CHARINDEX(@imageTokenStart, msg, 0) + LEN(@imageTokenStart)))
    FROM (SELECT @str as msg) tmp   
    WHERE CHARINDEX(@imageTokenStart,msg,0)>0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT RIGHT(msg,(LEN(msg)- CHARINDEX(@imageTokenEnd,msg,CHARINDEX(@imageTokenStart, msg, 0) + 1)))
        ,SUBSTRING(msg, CHARINDEX(@imageTokenStart, msg, 0) + LEN(@imageTokenStart)
                    , CHARINDEX(@imageTokenEnd, msg, 
                        CHARINDEX(@imageTokenStart, msg, 0) + 1) - (CHARINDEX(@imageTokenStart, msg, 0) + LEN(@imageTokenStart)))
    FROM cte
    WHERE CHARINDEX(@imageTokenStart,msg,0)>0
)

SELECT token FROM cte
```

#### Result

> header
>
> footer

Answer (score 2):

```
get all substrings #image:header# #image:footer#
```

Replace `#image:` with the start-tag `<X>`.

```
get all substrings <X>header# <X>footer#
```

Replace `#` with the end-tag `</X>`

```xml
get all substrings <X>header</X> <X>footer</X>
```

Cast to XML and shred on X.

```sql
declare @str nvarchar(max)='get all substrings #image:header# #image:footer#'

select T2.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') as [image]
from (select cast(replace(replace((select @str for xml path('')), '#image:', '<X>'), '#', '</X>') as xml).query('.')) as T1(X)
  cross apply T1.X.nodes('X') as T2(X)
```

Result:

```
image
--------------------
header
footer
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael, I use your other solution, CTE with recursive call, that I found here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4845387/1934137) which more suitable for my case